# Multiple exists validation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, eloquent, request, exists

I have three tables in a database, ***clinics, services*** and ***services_categories***. **Service categories** has a column **services_id** which **is a foreign key to the id in the services table**. 
**Services** table has column called ***`name`***.

Clinics table also has a column **service_categories_id** which **is a foreign key to the id in the service_categories table**.

I'm creating a request validation for the clinics in Laravel but I have to check if the service_category_id value provided actually exists in services_categories and that row in the services_category is of the type Consultation Services Type(name).

How do I improve this validation to work in that way?

```
'service_category_id'=>'bail|sometimes|integer|exists:service_categories,id',
```

Comment: I would recommend you to create a custom validation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation / https://www.larashout.com/custom-validation-rules-in-laravel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can extend your exists rule if you mean to have `where` clause to verify.

update your rule as follows:

```php
'service_category_id'=>'bail|sometimes|integer|exists:service_categories,id,type,<your required category type>',
```